# awk extract number from field

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I would like to extract the numbers a field contains.

For example filed `$5` looks like `[u8789]` I would need `8789`.

I already know it can be done with `echo "[u8789]"|awk -F'[^0-9]*' '$0=$2'`

But I need the same in an awk script, and I have not found out how to get the expected result without calling awk from shell.

thx

Comment: What do you want to use then? The question isn't clear

Comment: so you're reading from a file? Please edit your Q to include small sample data (file) and how you want/need to call `awk` .. Usually `awk -f prog.awk dataFile.csv` Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use grep:

```
grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+'
```

When `awk` should be used and you have `gawk`, you can use the `FPAT` variable:

```
gawk '{print $1}' FPAT='[0-9]+'
```

---

"From inside" of an awk script without the help of `FPAT` or delimiter artistry, I would use `gsub()`, like this:

```
awk '{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/, "", $0)}1'
```

Further reading:

- http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html

Comment: Yeah it is nice, however it is a GNU extension.

Comment: that is not a problem we have gnu awk everywhere!

Comment: Unfortunately not. BSD's awk is widely deployed trough MacOS. Meaning a default Mac would not understand that.

Answer (score 1):

**(g)awk scripts**

Your question is not very clear...

- I believe you want a script.

Following 2 examples

I) get the first 2 number in each line, (following @hek2mgl)

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN  { FPAT="[0-9]+"}
       { print $1,$2}
```

II) get all the numbers inside inside brackets `[...]`

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN  { RS="["; FS="]"; }
       { print $1}
```